# SQL Condition to get "a" or "b" but not both

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I am new to sql queries. I am writing a query in which I am suppose to return title

I have the following query so far and it works but it does not return me the correct result. 
If someone can guide me where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT movie_title, release_year 
FROM (
SELECT m.movie_title, m.release_year,COUNT(n.won), 
COUNT(c.actor_name) 
FROM MOVIE m JOIN ON (n.movie_title=m.movie_title AND n.release_year=m.release_year) 
JOIN on (c.movie_title=m.movie_title AND c.release_year=m.release_year) 
GROUP BY m.movie_title, m.release_year 
HAVING COUNT(n.won)>2 OR COUNT(c.actor_name)>2
);
```

I have looked at examples online but have not been able to get the exact result.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Why did you remove the 2 tables from the `FROM` clause? The query is now not valid (missing tables after `JOIN`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your condition to;

```
HAVING ( COUNT(n.won) > 1 AND COUNT(c.actor_name) < 2 )
         OR ( COUNT(n.won) < 2 AND COUNT(c.actor_name) > 1 )
```

Or using the more terse XOR as mentioned by a previous poster;

```
HAVING COUNT(n.won) > 1 XOR COUNT(c.actor_name) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That makes more sense to me but just a follow up question. Shouldnt the COUNT(n.won)>2 ? If you could explain just a little on that. Thank you for the help

Comment: You asked for 2 or more, you could instead use `COUNT(n.won) >= 2` but i prefer the terse version `COUNT(n.won) > 1` which is essentially the same thing. What you had originally would only get greater than 2, ie 3 and onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Most database systems have an `XOR` operator, which is exactly the behaviour you want.

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor):

> [XOR] returns `NULL` if either operand is `NULL`. For non-`NULL` operands, evaluates to `1` if an odd number of operands is nonzero, otherwise `0` is returned.

And from the [Oracle 11g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/doc.1111/e12048/conditions.htm#i1052219):

> `XOR`: Returns `TRUE` if either component condition is `TRUE`. Returns `FALSE` if both are `FALSE`. Otherwise returns `UNKNOWN`.

From a mathematical perspective, XOR stands for eXclusive OR; it literally means "One or the other, but not both". Interestingly, it's logically equivalent to `NOT AND`, so you could use that just as effectively.

Comment: I did not think of XOR operation. But yes that works as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is through union and another group by:

```html
select * from (select movie_title, release_year from movie m
JOIN CAST_MEMBER c on (c.movie_title=m.movie_title AND c.release_year=m.release_year) 
group by m.movie_title, m.release_year
having count(*)>1) cm
union all
select * from (select movie_title, release_year from movie m
JOIN NOMINATION n on (n.movie_title=m.movie_title AND n.release_year=m.release_year) 
group by m.movie_title, m.release_year
having count(*)>1) nm
group by movie_title, release_year
having count(*) = 1
```